# disable refresh on back uiwebview

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

1. I have a `UIWebView` and back button in it.
2. when a user click back it refreshed the previous page.
3. Is there a way to avoid this refresh?  I want to show previous data with no change.

Answer (score 2):

You should cache the URLs, so no URL is requested again.

Creating a URL request, you supply the cache policy:

```
NSURLRequest * req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:@"" cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:10.0f];
[myWebView loadRequest:req];
```

Comment: tnx. from which method i should do it? am new to objective c

Comment: somewhere you are loading a url in your code. Just search for 'loadRequest' in your project

Answer (score 0):

I thinks its better to check your view will appear method in that view